# How to better structure a DB for this need?

Tags: php, database, symfony

I am programming a web financial app in Symfony.
I have a Entity Loan in database, that is the main object of study. A Loan can also have deferrals, charges and forced payments. So, they are also Entities linked to main entity -> Loan.
Now, I need to implement some "containers". I need to make a Entity "more superior" than Loan.
Actually, the main object must be a Case. Case it's kind of : Case John Doe.
John Doe can have more than one loan. So, every loan is a "line of loan".
Each line of loan can have "regoneciations". In that situation, this line of loan is calculated in 2 or more separated loans, and in fact they all must append to line of loan.

So, hierarchicaly, it must looks like : 
Case > Line of loan > Loan 
One case can have many line of loans, and one line of loan can have more than one loan.

Relationship : Case - one to many with Line of loan ; Line of loan - one to many with Loan.
It's all right with this?

I wanna know from the code side, if this relation will permit me to display at index page all the cases like

Case Name : John Doe 
All calculations :
1. Line of loan 1: /loan/3, /loan/4, loan/5 
2. Line of loan 2: /loan/6, /loan/7 
3. Line of loan 3: /loan/11

Case name : Johny Deep 
...

So, I'm thinking that I will have an action in the controller, like `/viewCase/{id}` where I will pass the ID of the Case 
 1. Take from DB all the loans where case_id = {id}
 2. Group somehow all this loans by lineOfLoan_id
 3. At view page with foreach loop output them ASC

How do you think, it will work?

Comment: Yes, if you'll develop it without bugs then it should work

Comment: You should build it in the way you're describing, then you should make test cases that tries to fetch the data in the way you want and check if it works or not. In my opinion, this question is too broad in its current state.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I will try to develop it. I will let you know. Hope it will not require a lot of time :)

Comment: Guys, I append this 2 tables to DB, and test them, so they work pretty fine.
And ok, in perspective I have ideas about how can I loop through this structure to get loans by line of loans, and line of loans by case.
I get stucked in ... in what way to implement "CRUD" of this 2 entities - LineOfLoan and Case.
From the logic side I need to have a form/page where I can add/edit/delete a "Case". Creation of Case is limited by setting the name.
Same thing I need to create for LineOfLoan, and at LineOfLoan I probably need a dynamic dropdown from database with existing Case names.

Comment: And then, on the create/edit page of the loan, I need to have a dropdown with a dropdown from database with all existing LineOfLoan, to choose to append to one of them.

So, all together makes sense? Some suggestions, remarks? Thanks!